# Javascript Canvas bad rendered

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, render

I just experimented a bit with Javascript and HTML5 canvas and when I saw it in my browser (chrome) I realised that it's not very pretty rendered. After that I saw it in the Internet Explorer and there it looks even more crawful. I made a little Example: http://ios.xomz.de/
I just declared the canvas object in the html code

`<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000px" height="600px"/>`

and rendered into it with

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.rect(200, 200, 600, 200);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();
context.font = "40pt arial";
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillText("Hello World!", 220, 380);
```

for example.

Can you explain why the rendering isn't good ?

Comment: and what is the problem with that? what are you expecting to do that it is not doing?

Comment: By the way: sorry for my bad english, i'm from germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to the way objects are drawn on a float based grid (especially vertical and horizontal lines and thus rects).

See there for an explanation and a schema : http://canop.org/blog/?p=220

Depending on the size of your objects, you need to use integer or mid-integer coordinates and sizes for your shapes, the goal being to fill complete pixels in both dimensions.

For example :

- use a mid-integer for a thin line (one pixel width)
- use an integer coordinate for a 2 pixels wide line

(and extend the logic for rects)

In your case, with a line width of 5, you have sharper rects by using this :

```
context.rect(200.5, 200.5, 600, 200);
```

Demonstration here : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/TyNBB/

Comment: Really glad to learn it. As it's your first question on SO, I precise you're supposed to upvote and accept this answer :)

Comment: yeah :) accepted it but to upvote i need more reputation... :/

Comment: No worry. Keep the habit to say in a comment when a solution works and helps you : We like to know when we're useful (or not).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use "px", also I'd recommend not using a self-closing tag:

`<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>`

http://jsfiddle.net/c2KeD/

Comment: This changes nothing. See below for explanation of why both your version and OP's one are fuzzy.

Comment: This doesn't help like dystroy said